# How to redirect with the least lines of code Angular 6

Tags: angular

Commonly, this is the code used to redirect page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inventory-status',
  templateUrl: './inventory-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inventory-status.component.css']
})
export class InventoryStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  redirect(url) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
  }
}
```

In Html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary bmd-btn-icon btn-back" (click)="redirect('/main/manager')">
   <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
</button>
```

If I use code like above every file I have to import Router and create function redirect. How to put redirect function to common and only with one line I can redirect page. I do not use a tag. Thanks.

Comment: Use `routerLink="/Service/Sign_in"` or create shared component and use `@input` as url.

Comment: routerLink using for <a> tag and I don't use <a> tag

Comment: Why don’t you use <a> tag? This is exactly the purpose of this tag. Replace the button with a; bootstrap (which you seem to be using) makes buttons out of a tags with CSS. However it is simple: use the routerLink or create your directive similar to routerLink in common module

Comment: No, you can use routerLink on anything. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. RouterLink can working with button. @JBNizet Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use angular `routerLink` directive in your template code. In this way you can avoid writing function.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inventory-status',
  templateUrl: './inventory-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inventory-status.component.css']
})
export class InventoryStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Your template code will be

```html
<a routerLink="/main/manager">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary bmd-btn-icon btn-back">
   <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
</button>
</a>
```